# Laravel Scope based on BelongsTo Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 2 Models, a `ServiceInstances` That Belongs to a `ServiceTypes`. Service type determines some things and among them the service `length`

In `ServiceInstances` I am trying to implement this "pseudo" logic:

I need to get $this->**serviceType()**->length, but relationship method fails

```
public function scopeExpired($query) {
    $length = $query->serviceType()->length;
    return $query->where('created_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subDays($length));
}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: maybe '$this->serviceType->length' - with no brackets

Comment: Tried that without success - All I get is another error: `[ErrorException]  Undefined property: October\Rain\Database\Builder::$serviceType`

Comment: **Scopes should modify the query not execute it.** You will likely want to do a join on the service type table and do the length comparison in SQL rather than PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't execute queries from inside a scope. You can accomplish the same thing with pure SQL. Give this a try.

```
public function scopeExpired($query) {
    return $query
        ->join('services', 'services.type_id', '=', 'service_types.id')
        ->whereRaw('TO_DAYS(created_at) < DATE_SUB(NOW()) - service_types.length');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `$query->serviceType()` returns the relationship object, whereas `$query->serviceType` returns the model(s) itself. Right now it retrieves the one model, but when you have a oneToMany or manyToMany relationship it returns an array of the models.

The correct way of doing what you're trying to do is calling `serviceType` without brackets, as follows.

```
public function scopeExpired($query) {
    $length = $query->serviceType->length;
    return $query->where('created_at', '<', Carbon::now()-    >subDays($length));
}
```

Comment: Tried that without success - All I get is another error: `[ErrorException]  Undefined property: October\Rain\Database\Builder::$serviceType`